# How plant can control the gold flow?

Tags: meaning

At American Embassy, Hamiliton said this words to Regina, who lost her 
husband, Charles:

> I had a good man a really excellent man on the Rue Ponthieu but H.Q.
>   asked us to use the **plant here in the building to ease the gold
>   outflow.**

This is a dialogue from *Charade (1963)* film.

Comment: What is the source? I guess [*plant*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plant) is a person who does the following - "10. *verb - If an organization plants someone somewhere, they send that person there so that they can get information or watch someone secretly."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given enough of the context to understand this: see https://sfy.ru/?script=charade

Bartholemew, who works at the American Embassy, is trying to use lighter fluid to clean a spot off his tie.

"Dry-cleaningwise, things are all fouled-up. I had a good man, a really excellent man on the Rue Ponthieu"  Means "I knew a very effective dry cleaner who worked in a shop on 'Pontieu road'"

"H.Q. asked us to use the plant here in the building -- to ease the gold outflow." means "Our bosses in headquarters asked us to use the dry cleaning service provided in-house, **to reduce costs**"

So "plant" means a dry cleaning service. "Plant" can mean "factory or industrial facility". It's implied that the American embassy is big enough to provide such services. And "ease the gold outflow" is using "gold" metaphorically to mean money.

Bartholomew is choosing, for various reasons, to avoid talking about the important topics and discuss something trivial.